# What is \tmp\hive for in Spark SQL (esp. while setting it up with winutils.exe)?

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

This is Apache Spark on Windows.

What is the need of `\tmp\hive` while changing the permission with `winutils.exe`?  Can I change this path to a random temporary directory?

Answer (score 1):

The directory `/tmp/hive` is the default value of `hive.exec.scratchdir` Hive configuration variable.

You can find more on `hive.exec.scratchdir` in the official Hive documentation (in [Hive Configuration Variables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration#AdminManualConfiguration-HiveConfigurationVariables)):

> **hive.exec.scratchdir** This directory is used by Hive to store the plans for different map/reduce stages for the query as well as to stored the intermediate outputs of these stages. Default value: /tmp/hive (Hive 0.14.0 and later)

Spark SQL uses Hive by default in `spark-shell` that you will likely use early and often. That's the need for the directory to be properly configured.

You can change the location (using `hive-site.xml` as described in the [official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration#AdminManualConfiguration-ConfiguringHive) mentioned earlier), but...why you'd care if it uses `/tmp` everybody has access to?

p.s. You could turn the Hive support in Spark SQL off, but I doubt you'd like to go this path just to get rid of the issue (since that would introduce new and more serious ones).

Comment: I think because he gets this error `The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-`

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure where did you get this /tmp/hive thing.

All you need to do is setup HADOOP_HOME environment to winutils.exe.

Comment: I'd then ask this question to dig deeper "What do you need HADOOP_HOME for?" That would tell you that you need `winutils` to treat NTFS as a truly POSIX-compatible filesystem and `/tmp/hive` is among the directories required by Hive that Spark SQL uses under the covers by default.